# getting data from a list flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter

i want to get data from a list its working with the first 6 attributes but i wanted to add the  "description", "assetsideid", "assetnum", "location" and "descriptionlongdescription"
but it stopped showing data and i keep getting these errors (i got the code from a online json to dart)
i get the error from the  description till descriptionLongdescription
"The argument type 'Affecteddate?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Affecteddate'"
and thank you

```
import 'dart:convert';

Demandes azizFromJson(String str) => Demandes.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String azizToJson(Demandes data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Demandes {
  Demandes({
    required this.srMboSet,
  });

  SrMboSet srMboSet;

  factory Demandes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Demandes(
        srMboSet: SrMboSet.fromJson(json["SRMboSet"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "SRMboSet": srMboSet.toJson(),
      };
}

class SrMboSet {
  SrMboSet({
    required this.rsStart,
    required this.rsCount,
    required this.sr,
  });

  int rsStart;
  int rsCount;
  List<Sr> sr;

  factory SrMboSet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SrMboSet(
        rsStart: json["rsStart"],
        rsCount: json["rsCount"],
        sr: List<Sr>.from(json["SR"].map((x) => Sr.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rsStart": rsStart,
        "rsCount": rsCount,
        "SR": List<dynamic>.from(sr.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Sr {
  Sr({
    required this.rowstamp,
    required this.attributes,
  });

  String rowstamp;
  Attributes attributes;

  factory Sr.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Sr(
        rowstamp: json["rowstamp"],
        attributes: Attributes.fromJson(json["Attributes"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rowstamp": rowstamp,
        "Attributes": attributes.toJson(),
      };
}

class Attributes {
  Attributes({
    required this.ticketid,
    required this.attributesClass,
    required this.status,
    required this.statusdate,
    required this.reportedby,
    required this.description,
    required this.assetsiteid,
    required this.assetnum,
    required this.location,
    required this.descriptionLongdescription,
  });

  Affecteddate ticketid;
  Affecteddate attributesClass;
  Affecteddate status;
  Affecteddate statusdate;
  Affecteddate reportedby;
  Affecteddate description;
  Affecteddate assetsiteid;
  Affecteddate assetnum;
  Affecteddate location;
  Affecteddate descriptionLongdescription;

  factory Attributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Attributes(
        ticketid: Affecteddate.fromJson(json["TICKETID"]),
        attributesClass: Affecteddate.fromJson(json["CLASS"]),
        status: Affecteddate.fromJson(json["STATUS"]),
        statusdate: Affecteddate.fromJson(json["STATUSDATE"]),
        reportedby: Affecteddate.fromJson(json["REPORTEDBY"]),
 description: json["DESCRIPTION"] == null ? null : Affecteddate.fromJson(json["DESCRIPTION"]),
 assetsiteid: json["ASSETSITEID"] == null ? null : Affecteddate.fromJson(json["ASSETSITEID"]),
 assetnum: json["ASSETNUM"] == null ? null : Affecteddate.fromJson(json["ASSETNUM"]),
 location: json["LOCATION"] == null ? null : Affecteddate.fromJson(json["LOCATION"]),
   descriptionLongdescription: json["DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION"] == null ? null : Affecteddate.fromJson(json["DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TICKETID": ticketid.toJson(),
        "CLASS": attributesClass.toJson(),
        "STATUS": status.toJson(),
        "STATUSDATE": statusdate.toJson(),
        "REPORTEDBY": reportedby.toJson(),
        "DESCRIPTION": description == null ? null : description.toJson(),
        "ASSETSITEID": assetsiteid == null ? null : assetsiteid.toJson(),
        "ASSETNUM": assetnum == null ? null : assetnum.toJson(),
        "LOCATION": location == null ? null : location.toJson(),
      };
}

class Affecteddate {
  Affecteddate({
    required this.content,
  });

  String content;

  factory Affecteddate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Affecteddate(
        content: json["content"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "content": content,
      };
}
```

and  this is the code for importing the data its working fine before i add the descriptions

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp2/Service_Request/SR.dart';
import 'package:myapp2/main.dart';
import 'package:myapp2/Service_Request/second.dart';
import '../Classes/demandes.dart';
import 'SR_details.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DataFromAPI(),
    );
  }
}

class DataFromAPI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataFromAPIState createState() => _DataFromAPIState();
}

List<Attributes> MyAllData = [];

class _DataFromAPIState extends State<DataFromAPI> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Sr>> loadData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'http://192.168.1.30:9080/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=azizl&_lpwd=max12345m&_format=json'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonBody = json.decode(response.body);
        Demandes data = Demandes.fromJson(jsonBody);
        final srAttributes = data.srMboSet.sr;
        return srAttributes;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
    throw Exception("");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Liste des Demandes'),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SR()))),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Sr>?>(
          future: loadData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
              return new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
                    return new ListTile(
                        title: new Card(
                          child: new ListTile(
                            title: new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Text(
                                    'Ticket ID  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.ticketid.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'status  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.status.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'reportedby  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.reportedby.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'Status Date  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.statusdate.content}'),
                                      new Text(
                                    'Status Date  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.description.content}'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  new SrDetailsScreen(
                                      sr: snapshot.data![index]),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  }));
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Affecteddate? description;
//instead of
Affecteddate description;
```

here you're telling the complier it's ok to have null value i know what I'm doing.

Comment: the error is gone but it still doesn't give me any data

Comment: It's the new null safety in flutter, should read about it.. it's a layer of protection to your app from getting null values in unexpected locations...in your situation the value could be null and your not sure about it.. that's why you add "?" to tell that i know it could be null

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Affecteddate` and `Affecteddate?` is determined by **[null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)**.

> When you opt into null safety, types in your code are non-nullable by
> default, meaning that variables can’t contain null unless you say they
> can.

With it, variables cannot be null if they haven't got a `?` at the end. For example:

```
String myString = "Hello World"; //This CANNOT be null
String? myString = null; //This CAN be null
```

In your code, you will need to check if your `Affecteddate?` is null before using it.
You can use a null check `!` as:

```
Affecteddate? myOldVar = null;
Affecteddate myNewVar = myOldVar!; //If myOldVar is null, an Exception will be thrown.
```

or a ternary operator:

```
Affecteddate? myOldVar = null;
Affecteddate myNewVar = myOldVar ?? Affecteddate(content: ""); //If myOldVar is null, create a new (empty) Affecteddate.
```

Comment: is there anyway i can contact you ? i really wanna ask you some questions